# Returning ArrayFormula from multiple sheets, in the same cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I have two Google sheets with different Marvel characters (column A) and their corresponding home universe (column C).

**Sheet1**

```
| Heroes            | Count         | Universe           |
|:------------------|--------------:|:------------------:|
| Spider Ham        | 365           | Earth-8311         |
| Iron Man          | 467           | Earth-616          |
| Hulk Bunny        | 24            | Earth-8311         |
```

**Sheet2**

```
| Heroes            | Count         | Universe           |
|:------------------|--------------:|:------------------:|
| Spider Ham        | 234           | Earth-8311         |
| Iron Man          | 998           | Earth-616          |
| May Porker        | 11            | Earth-8311         |
```

In **Sheet3** this formula in each row `=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ";1;REPT(Sheet1!A:A;1*(Sheet1!C:C=A$2))))` (placed in column B) grabs the data from Sheet1 and return in like this:

```
| Universe         | Heroes                              |
|:-----------------|------------------------------------:|
| Earth-8311       | Spider Ham, Hulk Bunny              |
| Earth-616        | Iron Man                            |
```

Which is great. But I also want combine the data from Sheet2 in the formula - so Sheet3 looks like this (without duplicates):

```
| Universe         | Heroes                              |
|:-----------------|------------------------------------:|
| Earth-8311       | Spider Ham, Hulk Bunny, May Porker  |
| Earth-616        | Iron Man                            |
```

I want to modify the ArrayFormula to search in Sheet1 AND Sheet2 - is this possible to do in a single Spreadsheet-formula?

Tried `=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ";1;REPT(Sheet1:Sheet2!A:A;1*(Sheet1Sheet2!C:C=A$2))))` but it only returns `#NAME?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

`=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(filter({Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A},{Sheet1!C:C;Sheet2!C:C}=A2))))`

Used [arrays {}](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) in Google Sheets, and [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) formula. [`Unique`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198) is to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: This works flawlessly: `=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ";1;UNIQUE(filter({Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A};{Sheet1!C:C;Sheet2!C:C}=A2))))` - just had to change `,` to `;` since I have some regional settings - thank you so much!